# Unique referral code generate in django

Tags: python, django

I am new in django and i want to generate a **unique** referral code for each user with the **signup**.This referral code will be emailed to the user.I am using userena and I have no idea how do this with **userena**. These are some links about the issue,but not so clear how to implement with **userena**

https://github.com/byteweaver/django-referral

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-referral

http://paltman.com/2012/08/17/how-to-easily-add-referrals-to-a-website/.

.So if anyone have clear thoughts about the issue,then please share with me.
 Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to created a new model for hold referral code. below are given model syntax.

```
import uuid
import base64
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from userena.models import UserenaLanguageBaseProfile
from userena.utils import user_model_label 


class Profile(UserenaLanguageBaseProfile):
    """ Default profile """

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='profile')
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return u'/profile/show/%d' % self.id
    def generate_verification_code(self):
        # Generate user's verification code
        # TODO: Move this to the model
        return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid1().bytes.encode("base64").rstrip())[:25]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        If this is a new user, generate code.
        Otherwise leave as is
        """
        if not self.pk:
            self.referral_code = self.generate_verification_code()
        elif not self.verification_code:
            self.referral_code = self.generate_verification_code()

        return super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

add These lines in your last lines your models.py

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Above mention line will create your user profile at the time of creating user.

Hope this work for you!!!

Comment: i am facing an error... **NameError: global name 'CustomUser' is not defined** ,now may its occuring because in return,you have use CustomUser in as a parameter of Super.how to solve it? Yogesh

Comment: Edited the post  you can see now.

Comment: your answer is working well ,that is referral code is generating,but when i attempt to edit user profile using default userena edit profile option then i am facing an error like this **'Profile' object has no attribute 'verification_code'** , if u there please help me. @Yogesh

Comment: generate_verification_code  is giving me this error AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'