# Unique invite link to telegram channel using telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I want to create an invite system to a telegram channel (public but also later private).

I saw that a telethon bot can create his own invite link. So is it possible to get an invite link from a member of the group that is not the bot itself?

Or maybe anyone has another idea? Want that member can earn points by inviting others... so far I do that by a bot who asks "who invites you" and add the user to the channel but there is some trouble by writing usernames wrong etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique referral code generate in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876995/unique-referral-code-generate-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

The service message "<user> joined the group via invite link" contains information about the `inviter_id`. This can be checked like so:

```py
from telethon import types

if isinstance(message.action, types.MessageActionChatJoinedByLink):
    user_who_joined = message.from_id
    user_who_created_link = message.action.inviter_id
```

For the sake of completeness, generating a new link (and revoking the old one if any) is done with [`ExportChatInviteRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/export_chat_invite.html):

```py
from telethon import functions

result = await client(functions.messages.ExportChatInviteRequest(chat))
print(result.link)
```

Comment: Thank you! The first one is exactly what im searching for.

But the secound one is an invitelink for the bot. It should be used like:
User X send into the group "/getlink" and is getting his link (not the link of the bot) from the bot.